# Variable scope and global variable

Tags: python-2.7

global x means you are creating a global variable
or you assigning the existing 'x' variable as global?

```
def evaluate_expression_1(x):
    x = x - 3

    def evaluate_expression_2():
        global x
        return x + 7

    return evaluate_expression_2()
# Main Program #
x = 7
print(evaluate_expression_1(x))
```

Output is coming 14 instead of 18.What's the logic?

Answer (score 0):

With `global x` line of code
To get 18, x should be 11.
Without `global x` line of code
To get 18, x should be 14
Answer you should expect with this code minus the `global x` statement is 11  
 
The `global x` statement uses a later defined version of x.
To see for yourself, 
change name `x` after the functions to name `n`